# end of stream in JAVA

Tags: java, io, inputstream

I am confused by the following statement that appears [here](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week10/06.html)

> The basic read() method of the InputStream class reads a single
>   unsigned byte of data and returns the int value of the unsigned byte.
>   This is a number between 0 and 255. If the end of stream is
>   encountered, it returns -1 instead; and you can use this as a flag to
>   watch for the end of stream.

Since one byte can represent up to 256 integers, I fail to see how it can represent 0 to 256 and -1. Can someone please comment on what I am missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type of [InputStream#read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) is an `int`, where the value can be read as a `byte` if it falls in the range of 0-255.

Comment: Thank you. All three answers are the same, so I will accept the first one.

Answer (score 3):

Although the `read()` operation just reads a byte it actually returns an `int` so there is no problem.

Just values in range 0-255 are returned though, aside from the special -1 end of stream value.

Answer (score 3):

It returns an `int`, not a `byte`, so though it normally will only contain 0-255, it *can* contain other values.